# Adding onto browsers' built-in form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating an email form for our website. I built the form [using HTML5 and CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML) to take advantage of [browsers' built-in validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) (using [this shim](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/05/17/cross-browser-styling-of-html5-forms-even-in-older-browsers/) to avoid compatibility problems). Now I want to add a "confirm your email address" field, which shouldn't be marked valid unless it matches the "enter your email address" field.

I've written some JavaScript to compare the two fields. Is there a way for JavaScript to mark a field as valid/invalid for the browser's built-in validation? Or do I need to switch to a third-party validation plugin to get this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [the answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_combining_several_fields_Postal_code_validation) right after I posted the question. You call `<element>.setCustomValidity()` on the field, passing in an empty string to set the field as valid. If it's not valid, you instead pass in a string with the reason why.

Here's my code:

```
$('#emailConfirmation').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($('#emailConfirmation').val() == $('#email').val()) {
        $("#emailConfirmation")[0].setCustomValidity("");
    } else {
        $("#emailConfirmation")[0].setCustomValidity("Check that you've typed your email address the same way in both places.");
    }
});
```

Here it is again without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('emailConfirmation').onchange = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("emailConfirmation").value == document.getElementById("email").value) {
        document.getElementById("emailConfirmation").setCustomValidity("");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("emailConfirmation").setCustomValidity("Check that you've typed your email address the same way in both places.");
    }
}
```